# SAFE PDF merge and TIF conversion

Tags: pdf, merge, tiff

I need to merge somewhere between 10-20 PDF files into 1 and then convert them to a TIF file.
I've done similar quite a few times before, but for personal use with non-confidential documents.

Now, however, I need to merge documents of a more corporate nature, and I am in need of a solution that:

- Runs locally without communicating with a third party server, as to be certain that no data is stolen. (Unless the software is from a major Corporation such as Oracle).
- Uses software that can be downloaded from trusted and accountable sources.

Worth noting is that:

- Free software is a plus, but paid software is absolutely no obstacle, especially if from a major distributor.
- I am moderately proficient in PHP and have some experience working with FPDF, although this option is much less desirable due to the TIF conversion as well as the encoding needing  to include Danish characters (æøåÆØÅ) which to my experience tends to be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat does that nicely (and much more).
It is probably a cannon to shoot at a bird here, but a standard solution for corporate office use.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up picking as well. I'd want to add that Adobe Acrobat DC has a 7-day free trial worth using in this scenario to anyone else searching for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdftk` on Linux systems to merge, split, etc. PDF files.  There are also lots of PDF to $format converters, like pdf2ps.  So, generate your PDF file, get all the files into one PDF file, convert to PostScript via `pdf2ps` and then from PostScript to TIFF via `ghostscript`

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pdftk

http://www.rgagnon.com/gp/gp-0007.html

Comment: Nice, great alternative for Linux users.